# Why can't I use file methods on urllib2.urlopen() return

Tags: python, urllib2

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlope) `urllib2.urlopen()` returns a file type object.

Since it's a file type object I would expect to be able to read/write/seek etc. on it.

But the only file method that seems to work is `read()`. Below I have a little sample code with the output it produces written as comment.

```
import urllib2

page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.perdu.com")

# OK, prints page contents
print page.read()

# Produces empty string (because EOF), what if I need to print the contents multiple times?
print page.read()

# AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no attribute 'seek'
print page.seek(0)

# AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no attribute 'write'
page.write("hello")
```

I'm trying to understand why I can't it doesn't support `seek` and `write` methods like a file-type object should and what is the alternative?

I want to do some operations on the web content returned by `urlopen` such as append some text for example.

I need to keep this a file-type object (ie: the method I will plug this modified web page to accepts only a file-type object)

Comment: maybe [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) object can help you here?

Comment: It's a *file-like* object. What that actually means depends on what whoever is implementing it wants to mean. It doesn't make any sense to `seek()` on a network stream, so that doesn't work. Nor does it make sense to `write()` on an HTTP *response.* So that doesn't work either. Basically, it behaves enough like a file that you can read it like one. In other circumstances, "file-like" might mean other things.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comments the object returned by `urllib2.urlopen` is "file-like", not of type file. It therefore lacks many of the methods that files have.

If you really want the file methods then you should consider creating a [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) object (for more efficiency use [`cStringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#module-cStringIO) instead).